# Handling 500 response soapfault

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, soapexception

I have an integration with an external provider, based on SOAP. In specific cases, if they do not have the product we request, they return HTTP response code 500 - and in the body envelope write details on the problem.

My C#/ASP.NET application has to read the response. But a try/catch cannot pick it up as an exception. As far as I read other places, I need to be able to pick up a SoapException, but I cannot find out how to make that happen.

Thank you in advance for any input!

Comment: Are you sure you have that right? A server shouldn't return a 500 server error if the product isn't found. This sounds like a problem with the server software that should be raised with the external provider.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It is a region-based service, and they return a 500 together with an envelope saying they don't have service for that region. I also think it's the wrong way to do it, but it's a pretty big company, and I don't think I can change their mind, because they already have hundreds, if not thousands, already integrating with them.